# How to make an array of class objects in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to make an array of class objects, but my code doesn't work. When I make a Solution.new it returns nil, and I want it returns an array of arrays from words in each line of `test.txt`.
I'm using Ruby 2.1.5

```
class Line 
  def initialize (content)
    @content = content
    self.line_arr
  end
  def line_arr
    @content.split
  end
end

class Solution
  def read_file
    array = []
    File.foreach('test.txt') do |line|
      array << Line.new(line)
    end
  end
end
```

And now when I make a

```
foo = Solution.new
foo.read_file
```

it returns `nil`.

Comment: Ruby always returns one of two things from methods: What you tell it to with the `return` keyword, or if it reaches it, the value of the last expression in the method.

Comment: Also, your title is completely different from your question. Your question is something more like "Why does this method return nil instead of an array?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Line
  attr_reader :content

  def initialize (content)
    @content = content.split(' ')
  end
end

class Solution
  def read_file
    array = []

    File.foreach('test.txt') do |line|
      array << Line.new(line).content
    end

    array
  end
end
```

You need to add this 'array' row, because you need to return it from the method call. Also I simplified a bit the Line class here. Basically, this code can solve your problem, but consider using the regular expression for parsing rows.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `Solution.new` is returning `nil` in your example, it's returning a new instance of solution (`foo` in your example)

Your main issue is that `read_file` is returning the value of `File.foreach`, which is always `nil`.

For starters, update your `read_file` method to return the array itself:

```
class Solution
  def read_file
    array = []
    lines = []

    File.foreach('test.txt') do |line|
      lines << Line.new(line)
    end

    array << lines

    array
  end
end

solution = Solution.new
solution.read_file
# outputs:
# [#<Line:0x007fab92163b50 @content="This Is A Line\n">, #<Line:0x007fab92161be8 @content="Line 2\n">, #<Line:0x007fab92160d88 @content="Line3">]
```

If you want to return an array of arrays split each line by whitespace:

```
class Solution
  def read_file
    lines = []
    File.foreach('test.txt') do |line|
      words = []
      line.strip.split(/\s+/).each do |word|
        words << word
      end

      lines << Line.new(words)
    end

    lines
  end
end
```

The key line of code here is: `line.strip.split(/\s+/)` which first strips leading and trailing whitespace from the string, then converts it to an array by splitting the string based on whitespace (the `/s+/` regex matches one or more blank characters).

**Some other suggestions:**

Pass the filename as an argument to `read_file` you can set a default argument if you want to:

```
class Solution
  def read_file(filename = 'test.txt')
    array = []
    File.foreach(filename) do |line|
      array << Line.new(line)
    end

    array
  end
end
```

Finally, for a much more elegant solution, you can use `map`, and simply call `.split` to return a nested array. The `Line` class isn't really doing much in this case.

```
class Solution
  def read_file
    File.foreach('test.txt').map do |line|
      line.strip.split(/\s+/)
    end
  end
end
```

This will simply return an array of arrays, where the inner array contains the words for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Line 
  def initialize (content)
    @content = content
    self.line_arr
  end
  def line_arr
    @content.split
  end
end

class Solution

  def initialize
     self.read_file 
  end

  def read_file
    array = []
    File.foreach('test.txt') do |line|
      array << Line.new(line)
    end
    array
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) instead of creating unnecessary variables:

```
class Solution
  def read_file
    File.foreach('test.txt').inject([]) do |memo, line|
      memo << Line.new(line)
    end
  end
end
```

or, in this particular case, `map` will do the trick:

```
class Solution
  def read_file
    File.foreach('test.txt').map &Line.method(:new)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is get arrays of words, and you don't mind loading the entire file into memory at once, then it can be done very simply with the code below (the 3 lines beginning with `word_arrays = ...`, the rest are setup and output):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

File.write('woods.txt',
"The woods are lovely, dark, and deep
But I have promises to keep
And miles to go before I sleep
And miles to go before I sleep")

word_arrays = File.readlines('woods.txt').each_with_object([]) do |line, word_arrays|
  word_arrays << line.split
end

word_arrays.each.with_index do |words, index|
  puts "#{index}: #{words} "
end

=begin
Prints:

0: ["The", "woods", "are", "lovely,", "dark,", "and", "deep"]
1: ["But", "I", "have", "promises", "to", "keep"]
2: ["And", "miles", "to", "go", "before", "I", "sleep"]
3: ["And", "miles", "to", "go", "before", "I", "sleep"]
=end
```